# Java set Font Color in a disabled Text Field

Tags: java, fonts, colors, textfield

I have a disabled JTextField and due to readability problems i want to make the font black again. So that it looks like its not disabled, but i cant edit it.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `setDisabledTextColor(Color c)` method to set the desired color. For more information check: [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setDisabledTextColor(java.awt.Color))

Answer (score 6):

Try using the method setDisabledTextColor (inherited from JTextComponent)

Answer (score 2):

Please use `setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK)` to make your text color black.